# PTR record and dyndns

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, dyndns, ptr-record

I have domain name at dyndns.com and set at home smtp server. I try send mail to other servers but get error:

**550 We cannot accept email from IP 92.46.76.192 without a DNS PTR record. Contact your ISP/HSP to set up PTR record for your server.**

How can i set PTR record for this domain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a dynamic address configure your email server to relay all mail via your ISP's relay server.  By far the majority of spam originates from dynamic addresses without a PTR record.  If you try to send email directly you will appear to be a spammer.  This is why your attempt to send are failing.

If you want to send email directly get a static IP address.  You will need to get the PTR record configured by whoever supplies it.  The PTR should point to a domain which has an A record for the static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Only your ISP can change PTR:

```
person:         Nurzhan Sakenov
address:        JSC Kazakhtelecom, Astana Affiliate
address:        55 Kenesary Str
address:        Astana, 010000
address:        Kazakhstan
phone:          +7 7172 330402
e-mail:         nurzhan.sakenov@astanatelecom.kz
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the provider, if you have a business account with static ip, they will change the record for either free or for a nominal fee.